# PHP, manipulating very big image files without loading them into RAM

Tags: php, image, algorithm

I've been searching about this for a while but I didn't find what I wanted, so here is my problem:

using PHP,
 I want to create a very big image file,lets say 20000 gigapixels, then I want to add a small image to specific location on this big image. My computer doesn't have enough RAM to load up the entire image and manipulate pixels that way, so I think I need to access the image data on hard disk and manipulate them in some way, so anyone knows how to do this? 
thanks for helping me out :)

Comment: Without you telling us what PHP-specific code or library you used to manipulate the image - we can't help you.

Comment: [windows / linux] ? [gd / gd2 / imagick] ?

Comment: @N.B.: I have not created any image yet! so the first step is creating the image, lets start by creating a 300,000X600,000 pixel blank/white image, how to do that?

Comment: @kaᵠ I am running appserv on windows to host my php applications. i have no idea which library i should use, i tested GD for creating a 20,000X20,000 pixel image and it didnt work, it worked for smaller image sizes though.

Answer (score 2):

ImageMagick supports operations on very large files.  I don't see support in the PHP/ImageMagick API but you could call out (exec) to the command line program and use one of it's disk caching or streaming options.

There is some documentation for dealing with large files here: [www.imagemagick.org](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#massive).

Comment: I definitely agree you may want to do that in the command line. If you must read, use two fopen pointers (one to read source, one to write dest) and load the file small bits at the time, using fread and fwrite to read only parts of the file at the same time.

Comment: thanks for introducing imagemagick.org I am checking opportunities its providing, I was looking at the binary installation files for windows and from their names its seems the maximum pixel bit depth it is supporting is 16 bits..i am not sure if its enough for what i am going to do

Answer (score 1):

What would you do with an image that size? You couldn't serve it a browser, and even if you did manage to load it into the server, it would take up all the server resources, so you wouldn't be using the server for anything else in the meanwhile.

The short answer is that handling an image of that kind of scale as a single file in RAM is out of the question unless you've got an extremely powerful machine dedicated to it, and nothing else. At 20k x 20k pixels, even a simple monchrome image is going to take 400mb. Scale that up to any useful colour depth, and you're talking about gigabytes of RAM just to hold the graphic, and that's before we even start thinking about actually doing stuff with it.

I guess the solution is to look at what other people do, given the same problem.

Real applications that use images of that scale (eg mapping apps or panorama photos like [this one](http://btlondon2012.co.uk/pano.html)) store their image as a series of much smaller blocks. Each block is a smaller image in its own right. They'd also usually have separate sets of blocks for each zoom level too. Handling a single massive image file is implausible for any realistic server environment, but smaller chunks make it easy to handle for both browser and server. The server just sends the blocks to the user that are in the current view; when the user scrolls or zooms, they get sent more blocks.

Your question mentions adding a smaller image to a specific location on the big one. Again, looking at how others do this, google maps and others handle this kind of thing using a layering system. The layers are built up and sent to the browser separately.

I know that doesn't directly answer the question, but I hope it gives you some options to think about.

Comment: actually what I am going to do is to pragmatically create a raster map. I have tools to create tiled images as you mentioned, but these tools catch the main big image file and then create tiles out of it, such as technologies used with gigapan.org, MS's deepzoom project (zoom.it). so before I stand in the tiling zone, I need to create the image file.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess then, I'd question whether PHP is the right tool for the job. Just write an imagemagick script. (Sure you can use imagemagick from within PHP, but it'll be just as easy to script it directly, and without the overhead of PHP)

Comment: @alireza-mn - could you not firstly tile the very large image and then composite your overlay images into the appropriate tiles?

Answer (score 0):

Just keep a simple file, not image, and store pixel data in it in any custom format. PHP has a fseek function, which allows you to jump to any location in the file, so you can calculate needed location & perform read/write on it. If you have image with size W x H, and if each pixel takes 3 bytes, then the address of pixel (X, Y) in the file will be (W * Y + X) * 3.